# How to know if no more values are present in the array as you iterate the array in a loop

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

So, I have a `locations` table in database which contains the `seller_id`. Many locations can have the same seller_id while locations are unique.

In the function, I get an input array which is the list of locations and each location has another array which is list of variants. Example

```
$data = [
    23 => [40 => 1, 25 => 2],
    6 => [22 => 3, 24 => 4],
    28 => [22 => 3, 24 => 4],
    18 => [22 => 3, 24 => 4],
]
```

So here, `23,6,28 and 18` are the locations and `40,25,22,24` are the variants.

The problem here is, I need an array of `seller_id`'s and each `seller_id` will have the array of their respective variants. And I need to do it in an optimised way.

I figure it's something of this sort,

```
$locationIDs = collect($inventoryData)->keys();
$locationBySellers = Location::whereIn('id', $locationIDs)->pluck('seller_id','id');
foreach ($locationBySellers as $location => $seller) {
    $variants = array_keys($data[$location]);
    echo "Seller: ".$seller.", Variants: ".$variants."\n";
    //How to know if no more sellers are present with value $seller
}
```

Can you help me with this. Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `$data` is what you can pull from database. The following code will get the seller_id and their respective variants.

```
$data = [
    23 => [40 => 1, 25 => 2],
    6 => [22 => 3, 24 => 4],
    28 => [22 => 3, 24 => 4],
    18 => [22 => 3, 24 => 4],
];

foreach ($data as $location => $seller) {
    $variants = array_keys($data[$location]);
    foreach($seller as $variant=>$id) {
        if(!isset($sellers[$id])) $sellers[$id]=[];
        if(!in_array($variant,$sellers[$id])) array_push($sellers[$id],$variant);
    }
   // echo "Seller: ".$seller.", Variants: ".$variants."\n";
   //How to know if no more sellers are present with value $seller
}
var_dump($sellers);
```

And it will output `array(4) { [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(40) } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(25) } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(22) } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(24) } }`.